# jquery mouseenter and mouseleave not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that is hidden when my page is loaded, and on `mouseenter` I want it to show, then hide again on `mouseleave`.

**HTML**

```
    <div id = "t" style='position:absolute; top:0; left:50%;'>
        <button id="toggle" type="button" class="btn btn-default" >Toggle Arrows</button>
    </div>
```

**Enter / Leave**

```
    $( '#toggle' ).mouseenter(function(){
        $('#toggle').show();
})

    $( '#toggle' ).mouseleave(function(){ 
        $('#toggle').hide();
})
```

I changed my button to not hide to test this, and the only things that works is that the button hides, but it does so when I actually click it, rather than when I hover over it. The other problem is that I can't figure out any way to get the button to show again. I tried to use `.hover(function(){})` but did not get that to work either. Any suggestions?

**Closest**

```
$( '#t' ).hover(function(){
        $('#toggle').css("opacity",1);
},function(){ 
        $('#toggle').css("opacity",0);
})
```

Above is the closest I got to my answer but it does not work on hover, instead it works when I click the button and off the button.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle so we can see whats going on? Not really sure from your question

Comment: If you hide the button, what trigger then exists for it to be shown?

Comment: How do you hover over something that isn't there? The logic seems flawed!

Comment: @j08691 I have tried using opacity, onmouseover events, hide/show, visibility, and display. Nothing is working. Once the button is hidden it does not come back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work with the follow HTML and Javascript. My biggest problem was that when I hid the element, I could not get it back but no answers worked for me but this one (thanks to all who tried).

**HTML**

```
    <div id = "t" style='position:absolute; top:0; right:0;' onmouseover="showButton()" onmouseout="hideButton()">
        <button id="toggle" type="button" class="btn btn-default" >Toggle Arrows</button>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function showButton(){
    document.getElementById('toggle').style.visibility ='visible';
}

function hideButton(){
    document.getElementById('toggle').style.visibility ='hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[jfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qSQyc/)

```
$( '#toggle' ).mouseenter(function(){
        $('#toggle').css("opacity",1)
})

    $( '#toggle' ).mouseleave(function(){ 
        $('#toggle').css("opacity",0)
})
```

better be invisible to eye , but as a DOM it should exist.

Comment: Tested this on my page and it only gets shown on click, rather than a hover.

Comment: by changing opacity button will be unclickable or not?

Comment: @JordanD no kidding ! :D

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes it will be . can be disabled if this gonna be a trouble.

Comment: @ProllyGeek even when I try this on `hover` it only works when I click the button (or empty space where the button is hidden). What am I missing?

Comment: @ProllyGeek Yes I have, which is why I am so confused why it will not work. Everyone posted valid answers that are working in their fiddles, but not in my project.

Comment: @JordanD can you post a link to your page , or the whole code you are using , also check console , are there any errors ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek , It is not live, and I posted the only relevant code. The rest of it is 1,200 lines of other stuff.

Comment: @JordanD and you said mine works when you click it ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek , correct and the `.hover` function has the same result

Comment: @JordanD try this : http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/qSQyc/1/  , and change button z-index to 10 maybe , or any other higher value.

Comment: @ProllyGeek This also is giving me the same problem. I am trying `onmouseover="showButton(this)" onmouseout="hideButton(this)"` on my button and using `function showButton(x){
 console.log('show');
 x.style.visibility ='visible';
}

function hideButton(x){
 console.log('hide');
 x.style.visibility ='hidden';
}` and when it disappears I can't get it back again. This is the weirdest problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using container div of button:

```
 $( '#t' ).mouseenter(function(){
        $('#toggle').show();
})

    $( '#t' ).mouseleave(function(){ 
        $('#toggle').hide();
})
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9MWuL/)

Comment: I tried this previously, but maybe I did it incorrectly. I will try it again.

Comment: your mistake was you not gave any height width to div

Comment: I gave width and height to my div and this still does not work. Is it possible once hidden, the div is getting pushed behind another element causing me to not be able to hover over it?

Comment: use ``min-height`` and ``min-width`` so div keeps a specific area occupied

Comment: This does not work either, the button will hide but never show.

Comment: I have been following all instructions exact.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code provided at the following link for [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CStv4/)

You need to apply the mouse enter and mouse leave on container not on the button. If that is being put on the button then it creates a problem that when you leave the button then the display goes none and then you cannot fire the reenter option again as the DOM element doesnot exist.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="" id="targetContainer">
    <button id="toggle" type="button" class="btn btn-default" >Toggle Arrows</button> 
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
 $("#targetContainer").mouseenter(function(e){
    $("#toggle").show();
    }).mouseleave(function(e){
    $("#toggle").hide();
    });
```

CSS Code:
    #targetContainer{
        border:1px solid;
        padding: 10px;
    }

```
#targetContainer #toggle{
    display:none;
}
```